# Multicast after service starts after boot in Android

Tags: android, service, boot, ethernet

I am using Android 4.2 on an OMAP4460 processor from TI.  My goal is this, start a service right after boot that listens for SSDP queries on a multicast socket.  I can do this but when I go to create the `MulticastSocket` I get an exception. The exception is coming from the underlying `datagramSocket`.  Here are some code snippets:

```
<receiver          android:name="com.example.reciever.StartServicesAtBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="StartServicesAtBootRemoteReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My `onRecieve()` looks like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent(context,
            myService.class);
    ComponentName serviceStarted = context
            .startService(ServiceIntent);
    if (serviceStarted != null)

}
```

And finally, the service snippet:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        if (null == ssdpServer) {
            ssdpServer = new UDPListenThread();
            ssdpServer.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public class UDPListenThread extends Thread {

    protected MulticastSocket socket = null;

    public UDPListenThread() throws IOException {
        this("UDPListenThread");
    }

    public UDPListenThread(String name) throws IOException {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

            Socket mySocket = new Socket();
            socket = new MulticastSocket(SSDP_PORT);
            // socket.setLoopbackMode(false);
            socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(SSDP_ADDRESS));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

etc.

Note: the `Socket` does get allocated (it's not used here so not sure if it is valid or not). 
Also, if I try:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getBaseContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

from the service or the reciever. `activeNetwork` comes back as `null`.  Even if I wait for `activeNetwork` (from the service) like this:

```
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
        while (null == activeNetwork) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getBaseContext()
                    .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "activeNetwork "
                    + activeNetwork);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

it remains null even after I am able to pull up the browser and search from the UI.

Follow up:  Turns out it was a bad kernel build.  I guess you build atop a trash heap, you get a shaky structure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you require all proper permissions for your application?

I think you may miss [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) or [CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE)

Comment: ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE i did use.  It is a hardwired eth0 connection, so I did not use CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE nor lock multicast.  This exact same service works when it starts as part of an activity.